# Array method returning all null elements instead of object elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have the problem with the following method. It is supposed to create an array, fill it up with objects, and return the filled array. However, for a reason unknown to me, the returned array is full of null values.

```
 public Rodent[] getRodents(int amount) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        Rodent[] rodentArray = new Rodent[amount];

        for (Rodent r : rodentArray) {
            switch (rng.nextInt(3)) {
                case 0:
                    r = new Mouse(); // Subclass of Rodent
                    break;
                case 1:
                    r = new Gebril(); // Subclass of Rodent
                    break;
                case 2:
                    r = new Hamster(); // Subclass of Rodent
                    break;
                default:
                    r = new Rodent(); // For safety
            }
            System.out.println(r.getName()); // Test command inside the loop. Prints the name of all object correctly.
        }

        for (Rodent r : rodentArray) { // Test loop outside of previous loop.
            System.out.println(r.getName()); // Throws null pointer exception.
        }

        return rodentArray; // Returns null filled array
    }
```

EDIT:

Found my answer. Thanks. Now i need to stop thinking about the enhanced for loop like a pointer.

Comment: You are simply reassigning a local variable. If you get into the habit of declaring your local variables as `final` when they are constant then this error would be flagged up by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r` is a local variable in your loop that does not exist outside a given iteration. Your code is equivalent to the code below where it is maybe easier to see that the `r` is discarded at the end of each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rodentArray.length; i++) {
    Rodent r = rodentArray[i];
    //your switch here
}
```

So in your case you should probably use a standard for loop and fill the array with `rodentArray[i] = new Mouse();` or with other animals as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, r is a variable. But it is not needed. It is just supposed to point out to an array element.

Mouse m1 = new Mouse();
Mouse m2 = m1;
m1 = null;

m2 will still hold the object. Thats why i think that losing r variable is not a problem.

Comment: @user2964403 it is a local variable which is a reference to the array element. Reassigning the variable does not change the value it is referencing. This is Java 101.

Answer (score 0):

You are never putting newly created rodent object into array. Here is the correct code -

```
public Rodent[] getRodents(int amount) {
    Random rng = new Random();
    Rodent[] rodentArray = new Rodent[amount];

    for(int count = 0; count < rodentArray.length; count++) {
            Rodent r;
            switch (rng.nextInt(3)) {
            case 0:
                r = new Mouse(); // Subclass of Rodent
                break;
            case 1:
                r = new Gebril(); // Subclass of Rodent
                break;
            case 2:
                r = new Hamster(); // Subclass of Rodent
                break;
            default:
                r = new Rodent(); // For safety
        }
        rodentArray[count] = r;
        System.out.println(r.getName()); // Test command inside the loop. Prints the name of all object correctly.
    }

    for (Rodent r : rodentArray) { // Test loop outside of previous loop.
        System.out.println(r.getName()); // Throws null pointer exception.
    }

    return rodentArray; // Returns null filled array
}
```